# Посчитать количество картинок в ubercart3

Tags: drupal

помогите пожалуйста посчитать количество картинок. я создаю ноду node--product.tpl.php и вывожу не й картинки товара следующим образом:

```
<?php
    print render($content['uc_product_image']['0']);
    print render($content['uc_product_image']['1']);
?>
```

хотелось бы посчитать количество картинок, которые связаны с этим товаром

пробовал

```
echo('<pre>');
print count($content['uc_product_image']);
echo('</pre>');
```

не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Установи модуль devel и проверь переменную $content через dsm()